# How to use the symbol which has been seen as constant in Maple?

Tags: maple

For example, I would like to use symbol 'gamma', but 'gamma' is a maple constant(approximately 0.57722). If you use it persistantly, it will report an error

```
solve({2*gamma > 4}, {gamma});
Error, (in solve) a constant is invalid as a variable, gamma
```

Do I have some way to use gamma like a normal variable? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of Maple you can use:

unprotect(gamma); gamma := convert(gamma, `local`);

acer's solution is better in versions where it is supported.

Comment: Your solution can solve my problem too. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In recent Maple versions you can declare local instances of protected names or constants, at the top-level.

```
restart;
kernelopts(version);

    Maple 2018.0, X86 64 LINUX, Mar 9 2018, Build ID 1298750

local gamma:

solve({2*gamma > 4}, {gamma});

                      {2 < gamma}
```